# DB2 Monitoring Tool LUW

Tags: db2, monitoring, db2-luw

I have a little problem with finding a monitoring tool for our DB2 Databases.
We are currently using **10.5 LUW** Version of DB2.

If already checked the internet for several hours, but the only tool, which is coming close to our use-case, was updated for the last time in 2009. So could someone give me pls an idea, how to monitor our DB2 databases?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IBM Db2 Data Management Console https://ibm.biz/Db2Console is the next generation of db2 monitoring, previously known as "Data Server Manager".

You can also try dsmtop https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0070123.html

If neither of the above suit, please explain more about your particular use-case.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and what I did was to develop my own set of tools. The code is in GitHub and it works with Nagios:

https://github.com/angoca/monitor-db2-with-nagios

Answer (score 0):

seen on the virtuell idug summer conference
https://www.idug.org

two vendor tools for LUW Monitoring:

https://www.dbisoftware.com

https://www.itgain-is.de/en

Comment: Any more comment on that? Pros and cons, etc.